# Adding an integer to a struct

Tags: c++, struct, int

I'm having an error like this one below

> "incompatible types in assignment of `int` to `int [10000]`"

I can't understand what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct words{

    string lexis;
    int sizes[10000];

} a[10000];

bool s(const words& a,const words& b);

//==========================================
int main() {
    int i,x;
    string word;

    //input-output with files
    ifstream cin("wordin.txt");
    ofstream cout("wordout.txt");

    i = 0;

    //reading until the end of the file
    while(!cin.eof()){
        cin >> word;

        x = word.size();

        a[i].sizes = x; //the problem is here

        a[i].lexis = word;
        i++;
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone helps me. :) 
Thanks

Comment: Do **not** use `cin.eof()` as the primary condition in a loop reading input. Also, check any input _after_ reading and _before_ using, e.g., using `while (cin >> word) { ... }`

Comment: `a[i].sizes` yields a `int(&)[10000]`. You'd assign an `int` to `a[i].sizes[j]`.

Comment: Are you sure that you want an array of 10000 array of 10000 ints? IT seems that your structure is not well defined regarding the usage. Don't use raw arrays in C++, use the more convenient vector (dynamic array).

Comment: You need to explain what your program is trying to do. What is `a[i].sizes = x` supposed to mean? `x` is a single number, `sizes` is an array, what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: You probably just want to change the declaration to `int sizes`, not `int sizes[10000]`

Comment: x it's the size of a word and i save the size of each word in the array sizes

Comment: Barmar you are right :) just had to change it to int sizes thanks :)

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to create a wrapper for `std::string` that is completely unnecessary as returning `a[i].lexus.size()` will give you what you are assigning to x anyway??? Am I right or am I missing something???

Comment: I am not sure if i can do it like this a[i].lexis.size() but the proble is solved :) thanks anyway and i will check it out if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using variables with names same as the standard library, in your case rename the two file streams `cin` and `cout`, for example to, `my_cin` and `my_cout`.

If you want to read multiple `string`s or `int`s use `std::vector` instead of array, i.e. instead of your `struct words` you could use:

```
vector<string> words;
```

and then to read from file you could do something like:

```
// attach stream to file
ifstream my_cin("wordin.txt");

// check if successfully opened
if (!my_cin) cerr << "Can't open input file!\n";

// read file line by line
string line;
while (getline(my_cin, line)) {

    // extract every word from a line
    stringstream ss(line);
    string word;
    while (ss >> word) {

        // save word in vector
        words.push_back(word);
    }
}
```